# Can a building destroyer destroy a screw pump from the z level above its impassable tile?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

If I build a screw pump in such a way that its only exposure to outside is the top surface of its impassable tile, can it be destroyed by a building destroyer?

---

The exact setup is:

z-level +1:

```
F F F
F I F
F F F
```

z-level 0:

```
O O O
O I P
O O O
```

...where "F" is a floor, "O" is open space, "I" is the impassable tile of a screw pump, and "P" is the passable tile of a screw pump.

The building destroyer does not have any other valid path to the screw pump on its own z-level (I know this matters for destroying locked floor hatches from below).  It is approaching from above the pump (z-level +1).

Comment: Not sure, but I'd say that it is possible. As an analogy of sorts, Dorfs can acually dig down in a diagonal pattern [(x, y, z) -> (x+1, y, z-1)], while seemingly they cannot do so upwards without a ramp being present [(x, y, z) -> (x+1, y, z+1)]. I would assume the reach of building destruction being handled by similar code to digging, thus enabling creatures to reach below, but not upwards.

Comment: Additionally, creatures might be able to climb down

Answer (score -1):

No.  Creatures cannot attack buildings on other Z-levels.

Comment: This is not true - building destroyers can destroy buildings from the z-level below if a valid path exists to the building.  [Details](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Building_destroyer#Destroying_from_underneath).

Comment: Then why can they not destroy a locked floorhatch from below?

Comment: Typically, because the floor hatch itself is preventing them from having a valid path to its own z-level.  If an alternate path exists (say, if the floor hatch is blocking one of two entrances to your fort, and the other one is unblocked), they actually *can* destroy a locked floor hatch from below.  The details are in the wiki page I linked.